# How to shorten render times for Smoke?

Tags: rendering

Thanks to everyone who helped me figure out how to make the smoke effect in my last question. I animated it pretty much flawlessly but I've encountered a problem, after letting it render for 7 hours, It got through 10 frames. I don't have the time to let it render forever. That was at 480p 30fps with no motion blur. I even turned the quality of the smoke down and it takes forever! Any ideas on how to shorten render times? P.S. I've already tried rendering as a series of images.

Smoke simulation. I have a domain object and 5 objects on flow to create smoke. I also have 4 objects that collide with smoke.

Comment: To get proper help please be more specific: How are you creating the smoke in the first place? Smoke simulation? Particles? Volme scattering? What render engine are you using? What else is going on on your scene? There is no magical button that will make things render faster if that is your question, there might be ways to optimize the render times, but first we have to have more information. **Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post to modify your question**

Comment: I am creating a domain and assigning 5 objects as flow. I also have 4 objects as collision.

Comment: I'm also using cycles if that matters.

Comment: I used the edit button now.